# Why order of lines matters here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a [Memory Game](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-edison-4x9mv?file=/src/App.js) and I can't understand how can these two lines order matters in the code:

```
const timer = setTimeout(() => {
   if (picks.length === 2) {
     //this order that works
     setPicks([])
     setCards(cards => cards.map((c) => ({ ...c, isFlipped: false })));            
   }
}, 500)
```

```
const timer = setTimeout(() => {
   if (picks.length === 2) {
     //this order that doesn't work
     setCards(cards => cards.map((c) => ({ ...c, isFlipped: false }))); 
     setPicks([])           
   }
}, 500)
```

In the first case, `matched` state  receive the correct updates so why similar cards match, but in the second case it seems that `matched` state doesn't get correct values.

I can't understand how the order of these two lines affect `matched` state

```
const App = () => {
  const icons = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];

  const shuffle = cards => [...cards].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

  const shuffledCards = useMemo(() => {
    return shuffle(icons).map((icon, i) => ({
      icon: icon,
      id: i,
      isFlipped: false
    }));
  });

  const [picks, setPicks] = useState([]);
  const [cards, setCards] = useState(shuffledCards);
  const [matched, setMatched] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = id => {
    !picks.includes(id) && picks.length !== 2 && setPicks([...picks, id]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setCards(cards =>
      cards.map((c, i) =>
        picks.includes(c.id) ? { ...c, isFlipped: true } : c
      )
    );

    const matches = cards.reduce((matches, { icon, isFlipped }) => {
      !matches[icon] && (matches[icon] = 0);
      isFlipped && matches[icon]++;

      return matches;
    }, {});

    Object.entries(matches).forEach(([icon, count]) => {
      count === 2 && !matched.includes(icon) && setMatched([...matched, icon]);
    });

    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      if (picks.length === 2) {
        //the problem is here, that order doesn't work
        setCards(cards => cards.map(c => ({ ...c, isFlipped: false })));
        setPicks([]);
      }
    }, 500);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [picks]);

  return (
    <div class="game">
      <Deck
        cards={cards}
        handleClick={handleClick}
        picks={picks}
        matched={matched}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const Deck = ({ numbers, cards, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <div class="deck">
      {cards.map((c, i) => {
        return <Card i={i} card={c} {...props} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const Card = ({ handleClick, picks, card, i, matched }) => {
  const { icon, isFlipped, id } = card;

  return (
    <div
      className={`card${isFlipped ? " flipped" : ""} ${
        matched.includes(icon) ? "matched" : ""
      }`}
      onClick={() => handleClick(id)}
    >
      <div class="front" />
      <div class="back">{icon}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't think we can help without seeing more of the code (like what `setCards` and `setPicks` actually do, and where `matched` is defined/used)

Comment: The link is in the question!

@AlwaysLearning

Comment: your question should include everything needed to answer it. Using external links is not a good idea because it could go away or change, which makes the question of limited use to future generations

Comment: but i can't put all code here, it will be long, but ok i can bring the most important part here, thank you

Comment: is this not an `async`/`useState` misunderstanding ?

Comment: @SamuelG

setPicks([]) in both cases will work after 500ms and in that duration matched should get the true values, so i think order shouldn't matter here

Comment: @CodeEagle - I am referring to async nature of `useState` = your `setCards` and  `setPicks` are not synchronous so the order is relevant if they depend on each other

Comment: @SamuelG can you explain please?

Comment: @CodeEagle there is a lot of code to look through above, but what I was referring to is the understanding - which you may have already, that setting state is not synchronous so the values will not be available immediately to calls in following lines that depend on the updated state value.

Comment: no, i think it is not the issue, i know that setting state is not synchronous in react, the problem is just in useEffect in app component, other code is not imprtant, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ISSUE :**

Here main issue is with the below **line position in code**:

```
const matches = cards.reduce((matches, { icon, isFlipped }) => {
```

So to understand the issue, first, we need to understand what is wrong with the above line position, please do read comments to understand the issue better

```
setCards(cards => // <--------- 1.
    cards.map((c, i) =>  // <--------- 2.
        picks.includes(c.id) ? { ...c, isFlipped: true } : c
    )
);

// 1. current state of cards
// 2. returning updated state of cards

// so, if you are aware of async behavior or setState, then you know
// the below line will always point to snapshot of cards when the useEffect run
// and not to the 1. or 2.

// So here cards is pointing to snapshot when useEffect run 
const matches = cards.reduce((matches, { icon, isFlipped }) => {
```

Now, let's see with both cases

```
 useEffect(() => {

    // Here you will always get the snapshot of cards values, which is currently available

    setCards(cards => // <--------- 1.
        cards.map((c, i) =>  // <--------- 2.
            picks.includes(c.id) ? { ...c, isFlipped: true } : c
        )
    );

    // so if you understand correctly, above code block doesn't make any sense for the below line
    const matches = cards.reduce((matches, { icon, isFlipped }) => {
    ....

    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        if (picks.length === 2) {
            //this order that works
            setPicks([]) // <---- this will trigger useEffect , and send the cards value from 2.
            setCards(cards => cards.map((c) => ({ ...c, isFlipped: false })));            
        }
    }, 500)

    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        if (picks.length === 2) {
            //this order that works
            setCards(cards => cards.map((c) => ({ ...c, isFlipped: false })));  // <------------- 3.   
            setPicks([]) // <---- this will trigger useEffect , and send the cards value from 3.
        }
    }, 500)

 },[picks]); // <----- useEffect is dependent on picks
```

**DEBUGGING DEMO** :

You can change the order as per your case and check the console and see what are the values you are getting for `cards` when you switch the order

[image: Edit #SO-flip-card-issue]

---

**Solution :**

Hope this will make your doubts clear, now If we are clear with issue, what's the solution then, here we can solve it 2 ways but the basic is common in both way and that is **Always work with updated cards value, in that case order doesn't matter any longer**

---

**FIRST SOLUTION** :

You can put the match condition code block inside the `setCards(cards => {` and work with latest cards values

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setCards(cards => {
      const updated = cards.map((c, i) =>
        picks.includes(c.id) ? { ...c, isFlipped: true } : c
      )

      // take whole code block and put it inside the `setCards`
      // and directly work with latest update value
      const matches = updated.reduce((matches, { icon, isFlipped }) => { // <---- HERE
        !matches[icon] && (matches[icon] = 0);
        isFlipped && matches[icon]++;

        return matches;
      }, {});

      Object.entries(matches).forEach(([icon, count]) => {
        count === 2 && !matched.includes(icon) && setMatched([...matched, icon]);
      });
      return updated;
    });

    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      if (picks.length === 2) {
        setCards(cards => cards.map(c => ({ ...c, isFlipped: false })));
        setPicks([]);
      }
    }, 500);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [picks]);
```

**WORKING DEMO** :

[image: Edit #SO-flip-card-solution-1]

**SECOND SOLUTION** : ( and I would suggest this one )

You can create a `useEffect` for `cards` value, so that you will always get the updated `cards` value and based on that you can set the match values

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setCards(cards =>
      cards.map((c, i) =>
        picks.includes(c.id) ? { ...c, isFlipped: true } : c
      )
    );

    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      if (picks.length === 2) {
        setCards(cards => cards.map(c => ({ ...c, isFlipped: false })));
        setPicks([]);
      }
    }, 500);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [picks]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const matches = cards.reduce((matches, { icon, isFlipped }) => {
      !matches[icon] && (matches[icon] = 0);
      isFlipped && matches[icon]++;

      return matches;
    }, {});

    Object.entries(matches).forEach(([icon, count]) => {
      count === 2 && !matched.includes(icon) && setMatched([...matched, icon]);
    });
  }, [cards]);
```

**WORKING DEMO** :

[image: Edit #SO-flip-card-solution-2]

Comment: I think i understand the problem now, but still some confusion about setting state and useEffect, is useEffect a run to completion function and setting state deferred till all statements in useEffect get executed? or render will work directly when the engine meets a setting state statement??

Comment: render will be triggered as soon as there is any change in `state`, `useEffect` will get triggered as soon as the dependency variable got changes.

Answer (score 0):

The code block you are asking about is responsible for resetting the card state everytime two cards are picked.

```
const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    if (picks.length === 2) {
    setCards(cards => cards.map(c => ({ ...c, isFlipped: false })));
    setPicks([]);
    }
}, 500);
```

The state of the picked cards `picks` must be reset by passing it an empty array through the hook `setPicks` *before* the card state is set with the hook `setCards` since `picks` can only be set if there is not exactly 2 picks made. Resetting the picks length to zero is required in the current logic you have because of what you have in your click handler.

```
 const handleClick = id => {
    !picks.includes(id) && picks.length !== 2 && setPicks([...picks, id]);
  };
```

Comment: both pieces will set the picks to empty array after 500ms, in that duration matched should have the correct values, this is confusing to me!